# Can Firebase/Parse run code at a certain time every day?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, firebase

Is it possible on Firebase or Parse to set up something kinda like a cron job? 
Is there a way to set up some sort of timed operation that runs over the stored user data?

For example, I'm writing a program that allows people to RSVP for lunch everyday.  If you have RSVPed by noon, then you get paired up with somebody else who has also RSVPed. Using JavaScript, the user can submit their RSVP in the browser.

The question is, can Firebase/Parse execute the code to match everyone at 12:00pm every day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with Parse. You'll need to write your matching function as a [background job](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs) in [cloud code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide), and then you'll need to [schedule the task in the dashboard](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-scheduling). In terms of the flexibility in scheduling, it's not as flexible as cron but you can definitely run a task at the same time every day, or every *x* minutes/hours.

Tasks can take 15 mins max to execute before they're killed, so depending on the size of your database or the complexity of your task, you may need to break it up into different tasks or make it resumable.

Comment: What about Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

**Just to confirm about Firebase:**

As @rickerbh said, it can be done with **Parse**, but currently there is **no** way for you to run your code on Firebase's server. There are 2 options for you 2 solve this:

1. You could use [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) and run your code in Node.js
2. You could use a different library such as [Microsoft Azure](http://onsole.firebase.google.com/project/salawat-af7a4/database/data) (*I still haven't tried this yet, I'm not sure if it provides Job Scheduling for Android*)

However, Firebase is working on something called **Firebase Trigger**, which will solve our problem, however it is still not released with no confirmed release date.