# is it possible to auto update data every day on firebase

Tags: firebase

My q is how the firebase update data auto? if I want to scan all notes and check some data by date and if this date pass so then update to status to 'pass',
What I am looking is task that run him self every X time per day or one time per day and change the status according the data time...

is it possible to do it with firebase functions?

Comment: There is currently no way to run scheduled code on Firebase. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38992957/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it possible to do it via firebase function?

Comment: We just released a Firebase integration with . Google Cloud Functions. But those still can't run on a schedule. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/firebase-cloud-functions-trigger-on-time/42796988#42796988