# Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a way to schedule Cloud Functions for Firebase or in other words trigger them on a specific time.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Update **2019-04-18**

There is now a very simple way to deploy scheduled code on Cloud Functions through Firebase.

You can either use a simple text syntax:

```
export scheduledFunctionPlainEnglish =
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
})
```

Or the more flexible cron table format:

```
export scheduledFunctionCrontab =
functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *').timeZone('UTC').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM UTC!');
});
```

To learn more about this, see:

- The [Scheduling Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html) blog post introducing the feature.
- The [documentation on scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Note that your project needs to be on a Blaze plan for this to work, so I'm leaving the alternative options below for reference.

If you want to schedule a single invocation of a Cloud Function on a *delay* from within the execution of another trigger, you can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to set that up.  [Read this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) for an extended example of how that can work.

*Original answer below...*

---

There is no built-in runat/cron type trigger yet.

For the moment, the best option is to use an external service to trigger a HTTP function periodically. See this sample in the [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) for more information. Or use the recently introduced Google Cloud Scheduler to trigger Cloud Functions through PubSub or HTTPS:

[image]

I also highly recommend reading this post on the Firebase blog: [How to Schedule (Cron) Jobs with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) and this video: [Timing Cloud Functions for Firebase using an HTTP Trigger and Cron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA).

That last link uses [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/) to trigger Cloud Functions, and works for projects that are on a free plan. Note that this allows anyone to call your function without authorization, so you may want to include some abuse protection mechanism in the code itself.

Comment: Find out `exports.cronReminders` works: changed the first letter of func name to lowcase

Comment: @Frank does this still hold true today? Or is there a better option, also once that is cost effective...

Comment: Nothing changed around this. Including the fact that `cron-job.org` that Jen talks about in the blog post is free to use.

Comment: The video from Jen has been tagged as deprecated. So is there another way to do it?

Comment: The approach is as valid today as it was when the video (and blog post) were made. The syntax has changed slightly, but I don't think this specific case is affected by that. If you're having trouble making this work, open a question that shows what you've already done.

Comment: From the Cloud Scheduler page: `Each Cloud Scheduler job costs $0.10 (USD) per month`, assuming "job" doesn't mean each time the scheduled thing fires, but the cost per timer? i.e. a job that runs every minute only costs $0.10? (excluding whatever cloud functions it calls).

Comment: @AaronAsh "Cloud Scheduler pricing is based on the job. A Cloud Scheduler job defines a single activity scheduled to run at a frequency provided in the definition.
The actual running of a job is called an execution. A job is not billed for individual executions. For instance, if a single job is defined to run for “every day of the month”, then that job is billed $0.1/month and not $3/month for 30 executions of that single job." Source: https://medium.com/@pascalluther/scheduling-firebase-cloud-functions-with-cloud-scheduler-b5ec22ace683

Comment: It's also possible to schedule a function to run once at a *specific point in time* using Cloud Tasks.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Answer (score 17):

What you can do, is spin up an AppEngine instance that is triggered by cron job and emits to PubSub. I wrote a blog post specifically on that, you might want to take a look:

https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2017/05/25/scheduled-cloud-function-execution.html

Comment: What is the estimated cost per month, for a cron job that triggers once every hour?

Comment: @EhteshamHasan Looks like it's potentially free: https://cloud.google.com/free/.  Currently 28 instance hours / day free; Also, there's Google Compute Engine's f1-micro instance w/ Linux running crons for free atm.

Comment: Is there any way of creating cron jobs at cron-job.org using a cloud function?

Answer (score 5):

It is important to first note that the default timezone your functions will execute on is the standard **UCT** according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#job). You may find a list of timezones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you'd like to trigger your function(s) on a different timezone.

**NB!!**: Here's a useful website to assist with [cron table formats](https://crontab.guru) (I found it pretty useful)

And here's how you would go about it:
(Assuming you'd like to use **Africa/Johannesburg** as your timezone)

For **2nd gen** (v2) functions:

```
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";

export const executeFunction = onSchedule({ schedule: '10 23 * * *', timeZone: 'Africa/Johannesburg' }, () => {
    //your function logic goes here
    console.log("successfully executed at 23:10 Johannesburg Time!");
});
```

For **1st gen** functions:

```
export const executeFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("10 23 * * *")
    .timeZone('Africa/Johannesburg').onRun(() => { 
       console.log("successfully executed at 23:10 Johannesburg Time!");
});
```

If you'd rather stick to the default timezone, simply omit the timeZone:

**2nd gen**

```
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";

export const executeFunction = onSchedule({ schedule: '10 23 * * *' }, () => {
    //your function logic goes here
    console.log("successfully executed at 23:10 UCT - Coordinated Universal Time!");
});
```

**1st gen**

```
export const executeFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("10 23 * * *")
    .onRun(() => { 
       console.log("successfully executed at 23:10 UCT - Coordinated Universal Time!");
});
```