# Firebase Run a Query each 24 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase database that contains a "reservations" document and "reservations history" document.I want to execute a function each 24 hours to delete old data from reservations but keep it in the history one. I can do this manually but I don't want to run the function everytime.

My question is:
Can be this implemented with Firebase functions? If not, how can it be done ?

Comment: That's currently not a built-in option, but you can emulate it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time/42796988#42796988

Comment: oh ok Thanks for the answer

Comment: I was just reading. Can I use this method?
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.