# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Send push notification 3 hours before an event

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building a booking app using Ionic and Firebase.

I want to send a reminder (a push notifications) before the booking time to the user.

Does Cloud Functions for Firebase support such triggers yet? Or do I need a NodeJs server? How should I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase Cloud Functions** doesn't not support this feature right now.
To create a time specific notification you need a server which can trigger the Cloud Messaging API.
However , you can handle this scenario at your app end where you know the time of booking and you can create a notification  whatever time you like to even if when your device is not connected to internet.All you have to do is create a logic . whenever a booking is made you create a **Time Triggered** logic to display notification.