# I want to schedule disabling of user after they are created

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron, google-cloud-functions, scheduling

I have this database which has a table for `users`. which is updated every time a user is created in my fire-base.

table structure is like `users -> {uid} -> (and some user parameters)`.

What i want to do is, for each user created i want to `schedule` its disabling after specific time. i tried using `node-schedule` but it is highly random, sometimes it works while sometimes not.

I have one cloud function which monitor an update on one field from sets of user field (user parameters). for example `isRegistered` field which is `1` at the time of user creation. and once it become `zero` function will release all the resource and also disable that specific user using its uid.

But i want one scheduler which will do this field updation for me after specific time lets say 5 hours meaning that user will have no longer access to my database after 5 hours. How can i approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)

Comment: I dont want a cron job which will execute at predefined time rather it should be dynamic , meaning after a specific time after user creation.

Comment: Either way, you'll need to bring your own scheduling mechanism.  Use it to ping your function periodically and have to check to see what work needs to be done.

Comment: pinging periodically will lead to more overhead when there are more number of users. what kind of scheduling mechanism should i implement?

Comment: Periodic polling is your only option currently.  You can use the advice in the question that I marked as a dup.

Comment: ok thanks, will look after it. But this isn't efficient solution. let me know if you come up with something else.