# Update firebase data value on specific condition

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update field value(enable_options) in firebase realtime database when current time at firebase server is equals to field value(start_time).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable use-case. Which step along the way are you struggling with?

Comment: Where should i write this specific condition so that when this condition met i want to update enable_options field value from false to true.

Comment: You can either use Firebase Cloud Function or write your own node.js program in a server. Here are some links which will get you started.Cloud function(https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) or Nodejs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: Simplest approach: Write a function in a setInterval and do a check every min, to see if your start_time and server time matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843880/cloud-functions-timer)