# Firebase how to schedule hourly operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've developing a Vue.js app in which the user is able to load personal appointments and deadlines.

I'm using firebase for the real time DB functions and for the Authentication.

I recently find out Firebase let you create some serverside functin which can be triggered by some events, like DB operation.

My aim is to have Firebase periodically check the users deadlines, and in case they have expired, to do something (mail, notification).

So, how can I write a Firebase function which get triggered every amount on minute to check for deadlines?

I found this [page](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) which talk about it, but I don't understand why they talk about App Engine and a lot of other things.

Comment: Guy just make an http-triggered function and call it from [cron-job](https://cron-job.org)

Comment: The solution really requires what that blog post describes: an external service to trigger the Cloud Functions code. For another example, see the video I linked from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time

Comment: I did it! Thanks to everybody for the links