# Update Firebase Realtime Database after specific time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Consider the following database in JSON format stored in firebase -

```
"root":
{
    "survey":
    {
        "1":
        {
            "survey_question":"Who is a better player?",
            "option1":"Ronaldo",
            "option2":"Messi",
            "time_posted":7854123265,
            "visibility":1
        },
        "2":
        {
            "survey_question":"Who is a better singer?",
            "option1":"Ed Sheeran",
            "option2":"Chris Martin",
            "time_posted":9865321245,
            "visibility":1
        }
    }
}
```

I can write a Firebase cloud function which is triggered when a new survey is created.
But what should I do to update the visibility to `0` after 24 hours from `time_posted`?

**Edit:** I checked out the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time) and followed the instructions-

- Wrote the function, in `index.js` file, which I want to be triggered and deployed it successfully.
- Created a cron job at [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/) with the below address of the function-
  `https://us-central1-<PROJECT-ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION-NAME>?key=<PROJECT-KEY>`

The cron job execution failed with the following error message-
`Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /<FUNCTION-NAME>?key=<PROJECT-KEY> from this server.`

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do a time diff using `time_posted` to check for `Date.now() - time_posted <= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` (ensure that it is within one day of being posted).

Or, on a `child_added` event, you could do a `setTimeout` that calls back after 24 hours and updates the `visibility` flag, but that seems kind of messy.