# Firebase - Cloud Functions : Always running functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new on firebase cloud functions. I would like to ask a question about always running or self-triggering functions. How can we handle these things? How can we implement always running functions or self-triggering?

Comment: By essence Cloud Functions are implementing a serverless architecture: they don't run all the time (i.e. permanently), but when they are triggered. You could more or less simulate that by calling an HTTP Cloud function with a CRON job (but I am not sure it is a good idea to call a function via CRON with a very small interval...)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thank you for replying. Then, we need to trigger them somehow.

Comment: What is your exact business (i.e. fonctionnal) requirement?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec A function of an app that keeps track of currencies. For example, keep looking at dolar/eur level and then notify me when it gets 1 or something. And another thing, keep looking at social media such as twitter and if a tweet includes USDEUR, then notify me. These kinds of things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions are snippets of code that run in response to events that happen somewhere else. Some example events:

- a HTTPS URL is accessed, either [from application code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), or [in some other way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)
- a [User account is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) on Firebase Authentication
- a [node is written](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) in the Firebase Realtime Database
- a [message is sent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) to a Cloud PubSub topic

There is no concept on a forever-running function on Cloud Functions (nor on other, similar Functions-as-a-Service offerings), although it's definitely possible to create a function that [gets triggered every minute or so (like a cron job)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time).

Comment: Thank you Puffelen!