# Can I schedule functions with firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, crontrigger

For example, I want to make a backup of my database on firebase every night at 0:00, is there any way in firebase to schedule events? And I do not mean to execute a task when an event occurs in some node. I mean changing the value of an attribute when it reaches a certain date, to give another example.

Comment: As of 2019, what OP asked is possible with Cloud Functions Scheduling. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `http` trigger *function* in *Cloud Functions* and call *that function* on a specific schedule using a third-party [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

This is the way **advised** by the *Firebase team*, as you can see [in this `functions-samples` sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron).

[For more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time).