# Delivering programmed content with timer on a Flutter/Firebase app

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I've been developing a Flutter mobile App, and I'm using the Firebase Cloud Firestore to deliver "cards" on the app. But I need to create a "rule" to change for another card each 24 hours, or if possible, to change every midnight in the user's time.

I don't know how I can do this... if I create a code for this in the app, will not this restart the timer always the user restart the app?

Please, if the solution is in Flutter/Firebase docs, invite me the link, I didn't find nothing about this.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make periodic changes to the database from a trusted system. Cloud Functions are a great choice for this, especially when using something like cron-job.org to trigger them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time

Comment: I read about Firebase Cloud Functions... this will probably work well in my project.
Thank you so much, @FrankvanPuffelen