# update firebase realtime database in specific period with kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am writing Kotlin Android App with Firebase Realtime Database, and I want to update GPS data in specific period(10sec), not in real time. I tried both `Timer()` and `Handler()`, but the update time was not accurate, sometimes less than 10sec.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time) but it doesn't help.

```
val myTimer = Timer()
        val task = object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                val gps = GPS(latFirebase, longFirebase)
                val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
                val userID = currentUser!!.uid
                val ref = database.getReference("gps_data/$userID")
                ref.setValue(gps)
            }
        }
        myTimer.schedule(task, 100, 10000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no auto-increment-every-ten-seconds operation built into the Firebase realtime database. If you need that functionality, you will have to either do that from the client-side apps, using a Handler like this:

```
val handler = Handler()
val timer = Timer()
val doAsynchronousTask = object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        handler.post {
            try {
                //Your function call
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
    }
}
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000)
```

Or do it from a server-side environment such as [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). Since Cloud Functions only run in response to triggers and don't have a built-in trigger for time yet, you can use a service like cron-job.org to emulate that. For that, please see Frank van Puffelen's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time).

Comment: yes, I do but it doesn't work and it keeps update in not stable time. I don't consider to use firebase cloud functions as the data structure has been constructed. my plan is to do it on client-side.

Comment: there is one problem which related to GPS. When I test the GPS indoor, realtime database updates frequently. do you think it is related to Android GPS library? thanks

Comment: In this case, just use it client side. And yes, it might be related. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used Handler() and input a bigger delay constant(100,000). Although not stable(it update the GPS data to firebase between interval 30 seconds to 90 seconds), better than the previous version(update almost every second).