# How to create cron jobs dynamically in firebase

Tags: firebase, function, cron, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know how can I set up Cron Jobs dynamically with Firebase? I want to build a rule engine using which the Client can specify the rules, actions, and schedule and based on that I need to schedule that particular rule. Since the scheduling is in the hand of the Client. I can set a predefined frequency for the JOB.

I know in Node.js I can do it with libraries like "node-schedule". But since the Client strictly wants to use Firebase and Angular. I can't use that solution

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to dynamically create schedule functions with just Cloud Functions.

The two most common approaches are:

- Have a regularly scheduled Cloud Function (say every minute) that then reads the tasks from a database, and executes the tasks that are up.
- Use a separate scheduler service that has an API to create schedules, like Cloud Tasks. Doug wrote a great article about that in [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Also see:

- [How to create cron jobs in firebase programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074188/how-to-create-cron-jobs-in-firebase-programmatically)