# Notification in a specific time in different activities in Android

Tags: android, firebase

How can I send notification to the user in a specific time?
For example: 3 times in a day ,weekly.
and these notifications are same and for each notification it will show different activities? how can I do this?
I just want to store the data into database and set all the notifications and the notification data comes from database.

Comment: I have explained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send [notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17) to specific users using Node.js. You can also take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767485/where-should-i-put-a-code-which-take-a-long-time-to-calculate/54767571#54767571) might also help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! but I am confused about how can I show different notification contents in a different activity page? I can only show one activity page. and can not schedule the times to notify. I can schedule time from firebase database. But I want to do this things in app. Is this possible?