# Firebase Cloud Function schedule on Spark plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I would like to have a Firebase Cloud function that runs periodically. I know there is already [a way to do this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) but it requires being on the Blaze billing plan.

Is there a solution for those who use the Spark billing plan?

Comment: The solution Jen shows in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA) uses cron-job.org to trigger Cloud Functions, and works on a free plan. Note that this allows anyone to call your function without authorization, so you may want to include some abuse protection mechanism in the code itself. I added a section to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time), so will close your question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. However, could you give me more information on how I can add protection to prevent anyone from calling my function ?

Comment: Passing credentials from cron-job.org seems possible, but you could also pass a custom header with something like an API key. Honestly there are probably many ways to do this, so I'd recommend a google search and picking something that seems it would work for you.