# Updating Data in Firebase Realtime Database daily using Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im currently working on a project and I want to give percentage of points to every users daily based on their current points available and  update the user data in my firebase database. I wanted to add points for my users on a daily basis using firebase functions.

I've looked up several guides on setting up Firebase Functions and right now I'm just not sure how can i update the data.

[image: User Database]

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp;

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
    await updatePoints();
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!")
});


export async function updatePoints(){
    try{
        const db = admin.database();
        const ref = db.ref("Users/{userId}")
        await ref.update({
            "points": "3000"
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Error occured:"+err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `Users/{userId}` come from?

Comment: isn't it pointing to the realtime database?

Comment: `{userId}` has no meaning where you use it now. You might want to start with a hardcoded path, like `db.ref("test")`

Comment: in that case... is there a way for me to point to the Users points?

Comment: The UID is not automatically available in a HTTP-triggered function. If you need it, you will have to pass it along. Note that we're well beyond the scope of a single question here.

Answer (score 0):

The project sounds pretty clear to me. It should be a three step process like this to implement it:

1. [create a Cloud Functions that runs every day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42790735),
2. [loop over the data in your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events),
3. [update the property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update)

If you get stuck on a specific step along the way, post a question with the [minimal complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi there, I've attempt to update the points to test out the functions and apparently it does not changes anything