# Can Firebase Cloud functions copy data within collections in Firestore periodically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to copy a document from one Firestore sub-collection located in say "Collection A" to another sub-collection in a different collection say "Collection B" using Cloud Functions? And is it possible to do this periodically?

Comment: You sure can do these things.

Comment: There are APIs for Firestore to [read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and [write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). Combining those would allow you to copy data. If you combine that with a [time-based trigger for Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time), you're well on your way to having the tools needed for your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs for Firestore to [read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and [write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). Combining those would allow you to copy data. If you combine that with a [time-based trigger for Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time), you're well on your way to having the tools needed for your use-case.