# Scheduled Load of Firestore Export to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am successfully exporting all needed collections from Firestore daily using a scheduled cloud function to the storage bucket.  I can manually import the collection data into BigQuery using Create Table and choosing Google Cloud Storage as my data source, defining the location and that it is a Cloud Datastore Backup (file format).  I can't seem to figure out how to create a scheduled version of this job ( I can rerun it manually from the job history ).  Any help on figuring out how to automate these "create table" jobs would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)

Comment: You can also [schedule functions without firebase](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub)

Comment: Do you want to trigger this integration in a function? If yes, in which language?

Comment: Have you tried to load the firestore data through the CLI as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#loading_cloud_firestore_export_service_data)? You could create a little cron that imports it through this in linux

Comment: Yes, I am loading the firestore exported data into Big Query using that example.  It is working fine.  I just can't seem to figure out how to schedule it.  It seems like a one off operation (although I can manually re-run it from the Job History list).