# How to access updated value inside onUpdate function using Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a personal web application project. I have an arrow function that is being triggered every time user updates document inside movieIndex collection. Whenever my app launches it updates isBeingReviewed field of a movie document from False to True. I want to create a cloud function which sets the value of isBeingReviewed to false after 15 minutes. How can I access the updated value and set field to false? Is timeout a correct approach?

```
admin.initializeApp();
    exports.newMessage = functions.firestore
      .document("movieIndex/{movie}")
      .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    
        const changedDoc = change.after.data();
    
        if (changedDoc.isBeingReviewed == true)
        {
            console.log("The current status of isBeingReviewed is equal to TRUE, set it to false after 15 minutes ")
            setTimeout( access changed value and set it to false ,1000 * 60 * 15)
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("The current status of isBeingReviewed is equal to FALSE")
    
        }
       
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a Cloud Function to run for more than 9 minutes.  The default timeout is 60s.  You won't be able to use JavaScript `setTimeout` to schedule some work for later, because Cloud Functions will shut down the code after the configured timeout, and the callback from `setTimeout` will be completely lost.

You will either have to use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to schedule another function invocation for later, or you will have to make do with writing a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to periodically check for changes to make.  In either case, it will require a fair amount of extra work - there is no real "easy" scheduling of future work.

See also:

- [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)
- [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)