# Firebase functions updating / deleting document after a certain time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a firebase function that would delete or update a document after 24 hours like Instagram stories. Would this implementation work?

```js
// 24 hours in miliseconds
const time = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{id}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Delete or update doc
    }, time);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if you can use setTimeout to implement a one-hour delay in Cloud Functions, the answer is no, it will not work.  Cloud Functions can run for at most 9 minutes (60s default).  After that, the function will shut down, and your timeout callback will be canceled.

If you want to schedule some work for a specific future time, you should use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) instead.  Either that, or use a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to periodically scan for documents to delete.

See also:

- [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)