# How to schedule function based on condition in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this condition inside a cloud function. The condition is that if the value is "true", then I need to schedule it to false after 5 minutes. The status will update to true, but after 5 minutes it still remains true.

```
if(status == true){
    let usersUpdate = {};
    usersUpdate[`machines.${on}.status`] = true;
    db.collection('customers').doc(doc.id)
       .update(usersUpdate);
    //wait for 5 minutes
    //change status to false
    schedule = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minute').onRun((context) => {
      console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
      let usersUpdate = {};
      usersUpdate[`machines.${on}.status`] = false;
      db.collection('customers').doc(doc.id)
         .update(usersUpdate);
          })}
```

But this doesn't work. Should I export the pubsub function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297948/3371862

Answer (score 2):

It is outside of Firebase, but Cloud Tasks are what you want for this.  Super easy.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297948/8698374

Comment: Thank you. I used setTimeOut because I wanted it to run only after 5 minutes and it works, it turns "offline" after 5 minutes, I didn't use cloud tasks or firebase scheduler, will that cause any problems in the future?

Comment: If you go beyond the free tier, you will be paying for 5 minutes of server time.  Also, the max timeout for cloud functions is 9 minutes.  See (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)